# How to generate alias for class templates?

Tags: c++, templates, alias

I want MyVector can choose std::vector or boost::container::vector. How to implement it? I can using macros, but what I was told is that they are not very safe. Thanks.

```
#define MyVector std::vector
// #define MyVector boost::container::vector
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++11 has alias templates. You can do:

```
template <typename T>
using MyVector = std::vector<T>;
//using MyVector = boost::container::vector<T>;
```

And then use it like so:

```
MyVector<int> x;
```

In C++03 you either use macros or a metafunction.

```
template <typename T>
struct MyVector {
    typedef std::vector<T> type;
    //typedef boost::container::vector<T> type;
};
// usage is a bit tricky
MyVector<int>::type x;
// ... or when used in a template
typename MyVector<T>::type x;
```

Comment: hmm... I believe there's something awkward with the `type` member typedeffing two different types :)

Comment: @xtofl oops, forgot to comment it.